# Angular 2 CLI + Webpack ng build --prod big warning

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-cli

my app builds fine. but when I build for production by typing

`ng build --prod` 
in my console, I get the following giant warning and strange `dist` output:

[image]

```
WARNING in main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js from UglifyJs
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:235,5]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:5310,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:5310,4]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable TypeModifier [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:5476,4]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable BuiltinMethod [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:5732,4]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable StmtModifier [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:5966,4]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable freeExports [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:8176,4]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable freeModule [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:8177,4]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable ProviderAstType [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:9022,4]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable PropertyBindingType [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:9063,4]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable RequestMethod [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:9394,4]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable ReadyState [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:9409,4]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable ResponseType [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:9422,4]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable ContentType [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:9436,4]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable ResponseContentType [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:9447,4]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable TagContentType [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:11792,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:12589,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:12589,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:15093,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:15093,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:15143,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:15143,4]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable ViewType [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:19907,4]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable HTMLCollection [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:21081,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:23278,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:23278,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:23323,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:23323,4]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable HTMLCollection [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:25631,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:27538,8]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:27538,8]
Dropping unused variable SAFE_SRCSET_PATTERN [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:33759,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:34293,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:34293,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:34392,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:34392,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:34498,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:34498,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:34603,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:34603,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:35538,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:35616,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:35679,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:35786,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:35851,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:35990,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:36101,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:36237,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:36331,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:36454,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:36577,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:36690,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:36836,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:36921,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:36945,16]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:36954,16]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:36963,16]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:36972,16]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:36981,16]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:37097,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:37164,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:37248,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:37315,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:37397,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:37477,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:37580,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:37681,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:37752,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:37819,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:37890,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:37960,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:38033,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:38107,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:38192,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:38278,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:38361,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:38431,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:38541,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:38652,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:38716,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:38780,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:38848,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:38916,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:38993,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:39073,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:39156,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:39257,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:39385,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:39534,4]
Dropping unused variable suffix [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:39543,12]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:39647,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:39747,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:39833,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:39965,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:40038,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:40119,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:40205,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:40298,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:40389,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:40455,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:40523,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:40615,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:40755,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:40829,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:40951,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:41051,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:41166,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:41260,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:41346,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:41509,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:41595,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:41681,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:41779,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:41845,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:41972,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:42049,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:42113,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:42241,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:42350,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:42415,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:42485,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:42565,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:42750,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:42815,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:42891,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:42915,16]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:42924,16]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:42933,16]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:42942,16]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:42951,16]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:43044,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:43212,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:43284,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:43398,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:43512,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:43605,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:43678,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:43741,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:43874,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:43967,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:44038,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:44104,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:44229,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:44322,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:44417,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:44479,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:44542,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:44691,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:44753,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:44836,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:44909,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:45040,4]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable matches [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:47583,12]
Dropping unused variable __unused [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:47891,4]
Non-strict equality against boolean: != true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:49247,15]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable transitiveModuleMeta [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:50293,16]
Dropping unused variable EVENT [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:50654,4]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable SecurityContext [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:58783,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:61560,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:61560,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:61730,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:61730,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:61842,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:61842,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:62014,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:62014,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:62075,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:62075,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:62180,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:62180,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:62667,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:62667,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:62726,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:62726,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:62933,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:62933,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:62989,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:62989,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:63114,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:63114,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:63236,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:63236,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:63351,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:63351,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:63391,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:63391,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:63515,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:63515,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:63805,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:63805,4]
Non-strict equality against boolean: == true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:63892,16]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:63936,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:63936,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:64000,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:64000,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:64149,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:64149,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:64322,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:64322,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:64362,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:64362,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:64421,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:64421,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:64513,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:64513,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:64558,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:64558,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:64839,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:64839,4]
Non-strict equality against boolean: != false [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:67116,47]
Dropping unused function _fetchSylesFromState [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:71181,9]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable strCases [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:72884,12]
Dropping unused variable renderMethod [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:75587,12]
Dropping unused variable __unused [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:76550,4]
Dropping unused function normalizeArray [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:79198,9]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:81819,12]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:81819,12]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:81843,8]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:81843,8]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:82393,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:82393,4]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable pathLocationStrategy [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:82878,4]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable hashLocationStrategy [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:82882,4]
Dropping side-effect-free statement [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:83003,0]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__src_dnd_component__ [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:82991,25]
Dropping unused variable appRoutingProviders [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:83328,4]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__environments_environment__ [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:83371,25]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__app_component__ [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:83372,25]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:93857,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:93857,4]
Condition always true [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:96729,4]
Dropping unreachable code [main.ff67c2edc2d42d6adb60.bundle.js:96733,7]

WARNING in polyfills.c27b87b9e504b84ce8dc.bundle.js from UglifyJs
Condition left of || always false [polyfills.c27b87b9e504b84ce8dc.bundle.js:3722,63]
Condition left of || always false [polyfills.c27b87b9e504b84ce8dc.bundle.js:3723,62]
Dropping side-effect-free statement [polyfills.c27b87b9e504b84ce8dc.bundle.js:3751,21]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable Zone [polyfills.c27b87b9e504b84ce8dc.bundle.js:3274,5]
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The warning tells you exactly whats wrong, u have a if-statement somewhere in your code that will always evaluate to true, possibly resulting in other code that is never executed.

This may be expected and desired behaviour, but then your code should be written differently. Refactor the if-statement and the warning will disappear.

This warning is just a warning, your generated dist folder is generated properly, so it is nothing breaking.

Comment: I need to upload anything else from this 3 files listed in my folder?

Answer (score 0):

Like stijn26 said: We intentionally configured webpack in the angular-cli to emit these warnings. They represent the optimization and dead code elimination that is happening in your code.

We don't have a way to suppress the warning, but personally, in my opinion, I like seeing this results to know exactly where my code can be optimized in the future.

Comment: In order to publish my application, I need to upload the `template` files in my app too?

Comment: Yes all of the files that end up in your dist folder is what you want to deploy. The index.html file should already have the needed scripts injected into them.

Comment: Is there any way to configure ng build to place the javascript files in a different directory for example dist/content/app/ folder while keeping the index file in dist/account folder.